# Most pythonic way to fit multiple gaussians using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x)

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
ydata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

It is quite easy to fit an arbitrary Gaussian in python with something like the above method. However, I would like to prepare a function that always the user to select an arbitrary number of Gaussians and still attempt to find a best fit.

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the function `func` so that I can pass it an additional parameter `n=2` for instance and it would return a function that would try and fit 2 Gaussians, akin to:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func2(x, a, b, d, e):
    return (a * np.exp(-b * x) + c * np.exp(-d * x))  

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
ydata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, xdata, ydata)
```

Without having to hard code this additional cases, so that we could instead pass a single function like `func(...,n=2)` and get the same result as above. I'm having trouble finding an elegant solution to this. My guess is that the best solution will be something using a `lambda` function.

Comment: The curves you are plotting are not gaussians, are exponentials a gaussian would have a shape `exp(-a*x**2)`

Comment: Yea I just wanted arbitrary data so that the example code would focus more on the `func(...)` aspect than the data.

Comment: Ok, but if you want to fit a sum of gaussians you can use gaussian kernel density estimate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70768237/12750353) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70861921/12750353)

Comment: Ohhh, bob sorry I missread your comment. Yes, I just wrote an exponential and not a Gaussian. :D Quite an oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the function to take a variable number of arguments using `def func(x, *args)`. The `*args` variable then contains something like `(a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, ...)`. It would be possible to loop over those and sum the Gaussians but I'm showing a vectorized solution instead.

Since `curve_fit` can no longer determine the number of parameters from this function, you can provide an initial guess that determines the amount of Gaussians you want to fit. Each Gaussian requires two parameters, so `[1, 1]*n` produces a parameter vector of the correct length.

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def func(x, *args):
    x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    a = np.array(args[0::2]).reshape(1, -1)
    b = np.array(args[1::2]).reshape(1, -1)
    return np.sum(a * np.exp(-b * x), axis=1)

n = 3

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
ydata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[1, 1] * n)
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! The use of `*args` and `**args` always escapes me as a hobbyist coder and when I see it used it always feels like magic. I'll hold off on the check-mark in-case someone has any other ideas on how to solve.